# Minimizing 2-norm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

Suppose I want to minimize the following matrix norm:
$$\min_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}, \beta\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}} ||A-\alpha B-c*\beta'||_2, $$
where $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times1}$.

Are there any standard approaches to solving such a problem? Note, that in my case $B$ is a constant matrix consisting solely of ones.

Comment: I don't see a beta in the expression.  Is b' supposed to be beta?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Try to minimize $ (A-\alpha B-c\cdot \beta^{'})^{'}\cdot  (A-\alpha B-c\cdot \beta^{'})=(A^{'} -\alpha B^{'}-\beta\cdot c^{'})\cdot (A-\alpha B-c\cdot \beta^{'})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$The problem can be broken into two subproblems, each of which has a closed-form for its least-squares solution
$$\eqalign{
\a B &= A-c\b^T &\qiq \a = \frac{B:(A-c\b^T)}{B:B} \\
c\b^T &= A-\a B &\qiq \b^T = \frac{c^T(A-\a B)}{c^Tc} \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the matrix inner product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm trace}(A^TB) \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
Alternate between solving for $\a$ then for $\b$ until convergence is obtained,

i.e. an Alternating Least Squares (ALS) approach.